elasticsearch query for selecting records where agent1 is one of the agents but there are also other agents
I have an elasticsearch index that has this fields: user_id, agent_name, city, ...
I want to run a query for selecting records where agent_name "agent1" is one of the agents but there are also other agents, and then select those that their agents are in more than 2 cities.
I used this query:
query = {

    "size": 0,  # Don't need the actual documents, just the aggregation results

    "query": {

            {"match": {agent_name: 'agent1'}

    },

    "aggs": {

        "user_ids": {

            "terms": {"field": "user_id", "size": 60000},

            "aggs": {

                "city_count": {"cardinality": {"field": "city"}}

            }

        }

    },

}


in above example if i run the query it first of all, selects records that just all of agent_name values is 'agent1', then aggregates the result, this way i get the result if agent1 is active in 2 cities,
but i want it to select a record if one of it's agent is 'agent1' and also have other agents other than agent1, how should I change 'query' part to get desired result?

yo! Is it correct to assume that agent_name is an array?

please explain more, how to do that?

I have this fields: customer_id, agent_name, city, ...
Assume an insurance company that agents call to customers for marketing,
I want a query to get other agents that called 'customer1', if 'agent1' called 'customer1' and if the city of resulted agents is different than 'agent1'

My approach requires to get customer_id, agent_name, and city preliminarily.
Sample documents
PUT /agents_and_customers/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"customer_id":1,"agent_name":"Joe","city":"Palmson"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"customer_id":1,"agent_name":"Maggie","city":"Palmson"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"customer_id":1,"agent_name":"Rick","city":"Stoneheim"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"customer_id":2,"agent_name":"Rick","city":"Stoneheim"}

Search query with bool and an aggregation
GET /agents_and_customers/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "customer_id": 1
                        }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "city": "Palmson"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "agent_name": "Joe"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_agent_name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "agent_name.keyword",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_agent_name" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Rick",
                    "doc_count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

